# Unable to run TortoiseGit + cntlm + proxy server

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I'm tryng to start using Git on GitHub. Unfortunately I can't manage to get it working, I always receive, when I try to clone the repository, the message "Connection refused". Since I'm behind a proxy server I suppose the problem is there, but I don't know how to fix.

[image]

Below what I tryed so far:
I open the account on GitHub  then I generated a key with putty gen:
[image]
I saved the private key (2)  on the disk and sent the public(1) into the github place for SSH keys:
[image]
Then I used the private key in the clone phase as below:
[image]

This did not work for me, so I tryed to authenticate with my proxy using  [Cntlm](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/&rct=j&q=cntlm&ei=PehkTonMN8uSswbMi72TCg&usg=AFQjCNE4N9kGV-AqeXOLw_Fw5r6xrjkcMg&sig2=LUm765jrIcY8VFAmm-3vyg&cad=rja) 
and setting it to point the enterprise proxy.
Then I changed the tortoisegit configuration as below:
[image]

but when I try to clone I'm always facing the "Connection Refused" error. 
The Cntlm configuration file looks like:

```
Username    fpollano
Domain      mydomain
PassLM          93D6A9F56CD43B4571101CC5806411F2
PassNT          5FD9AD7F1504A469D994241648972131
PassNTLMv2      7255AE1CBA2511A751F848FC34087011    
#Workstation    netbios_hostname    # Should be auto-guessed

Proxy       192.168.1.5:8080
```

( I even check with clear password, with same results )

Anyone know a solution ? Alternatively any way to get some of these agents log something somewhere ? 
Thanks to all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, it will help if you have the following environment variables defined before any pull/push **using https GitHub address**:

```
http_proxy="http://username:password@proxy:port/"
https_proxy="http://username:password@proxy:port/"
HOME=C:\Path\To\HOME
```

([`http_proxy` in lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy/397642#397642))

Your %HOME% (which isn't defined by default on Windows) can be any path, but it must be the parent directory of your `.ssh` which contains your id_rsa.pub and id_rsa files (your public and private keys)

In your %HOME%, you will also need an [`_netrc` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows/6031266#6031266):

```
machine github.com
login loginGitHub
password passwordGitHub
```

From there, you will be able to clone your GitHub repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/Login/repo
```

To debug those kind of connection errors, [set `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy/128198#128198), and [make sure your CApath is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778042/github-error-cloning-my-private-repository/3778244#3778244).

```
git config --system http.sslcainfo "C:\path\to\your\git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Unfortunately the error is the same. BTW, do you really need to put my password in clear in all that places ?

Comment: @Felice: for the proxy and curl, yes, you need to put your passwords (one for the proxy, one for your GitHub account). That is why I usually define a `HOME` in a private directory (the windows `HOMEDIR` or any network directory accessible only by me). Regarding your errors, did you try first to clone through the command line? If yes, what is the output with `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`?

Comment: well I tried with gitbash and the output is:ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly ( in any case +1 for your patience :) )

Comment: ok, I'm an idiot: i figured out that I was not using https:// when cloning from tortoise, but git, so it wanto to use port 22. It's ok thanks for your help

Comment: @Felice: Excellent :) So, the output did help (which is why I prefer debug first in command-line, and then use the graphic tool)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. Our Sys admin forced Internet traffic to go through a proxy and I was suddenly unable to push/pull to/from GitHub. I tried VonC's answer with no luck.  Fortunately our Sys Admin whitelisted github.com on the Firewall and I was back in business. So it doesn't hurt to ask. :)