# Egit works, but TortoiseGit does not

Tags: git, egit, tortoisegit

I have been playing around with this forever and cannot find a solution.  For some reason, EGit that is built into Eclipse works fine with my remote repository.  The Git plugin built into IntelliJ does not work.  Neither does TortoiseGit.  They both hang trying to connect to my remote server (503 error).  I have my Git configuration set up through a proxy too.  I've looked through every setting of EGit and just cannot figure out what would cause that to work and not the others.  Are ideas for what could cause this problem?

edit:
**The plot thickens**

I am able to clone my project using cygwin, but not with the Git exe's I install.  I cannot use Cygwin with TortoiseGit though.  Could this be some sort of permissions error?

Comment: So I "solved" this.  What I ended up doing was just pointing the target for both TortoiseGit and IntelliJ to the git.exe found in my cygwin folder.  Not sure why my normal git.exe won't work.  I'm leaving this as unsolved for now in case someone finds an actual solution to my "fix".  Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: Eclipse usually automatically picks up proxy information. If your other tools don't have proxy setup correctly the effect would be just as described.

Comment: Woudl this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310041/unable-to-run-tortoisegit-cntlm-proxy-server