# Why can't I pull/push to our project repository?

Tags: git, powershell, github

We have few private repositories for our projects that I use all the time. But all of a sudden since yesterday I can't seem to pull or push for one particular repo.

When I am trying to pull/push, this is the error message I am getting: `fatal: bad config value for 'core.hidedotfiles' in .git/config` And this is what I found in the `.git/config` file (which I **never** mess around):

```
    [core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = false
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
symlinks = false
ignorecase = true
hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
    [remote "origin"]
url = https://github.com/CompanyNane/repo.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    [branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

After comparing this file with my other projects' `.git/config` files, I noticed this one somehow had the extra `hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly` line in it. So I removed that line and tried to `pull` without success:

```
  error: error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
  while accessing https://github.com/CompanyNane/repo.git/info/refs

  fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Then I tried [this suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778042/github-error-cloning-my-private-repository) but got yet another error message:

```
  error: error:0D0C50A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:unknown message digest algorithm while accessing https://github.com/CompanyNane/repo.git/info/refs

  fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I have already...

- deleted the repo from my machine and cloned it again (& the `.git/config` file still has the `hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly` line. Yesterday i asked my colleagues if they can pull/push to the repo...and they can. not making any sense to me)
- re-installed my Git

and repeated the above steps, but that didn't solve the problem. Now I am totally confused and need help! How can I fix this issue? Even after I never messed around these config files, I am just confused how did the file got altered?!

BTW, I usually use one of the following applications to commit my changes to the repository...

- GitBash
- GitHub GUI
- Windows PowerShell
- and as you might have guessed already, I am using **Windows** 7 :)

I appreciate your time and help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hidedotfile doesn't seem to be part of a [regular config file](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), which explains your first error message.

It is best to try and clone again (in a different path) the repo, instead of dealing with a possible corrupted local config file (`.git/config`)

If you clone it again... and the local config is still incorrect, one explanation is because of a [TEMPLATE DIRECTORY](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory) in place, which would copy on `git init` (or `git clone`). Check if you don't have, for instance, an environment variable `GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR` defined.

Comment: Thank you VonC for your reply. I forgot to mention that i already tried what you have suggested and looks like that .git/config file also has the "hidedotfile" in it. I am just surprised how my other colleagues are able to pull/push w/ this confiq and I can't :/

Comment: @Walahh Ok, I have edited the answer to address that.

Comment: i know it sounds very dumb, but i don't know where this `GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR` is defined and what to do with it! also, now i am having issue with my SSH.rb file :( I am just going to reinstall EVERYTHING (ruby, devKit, git, vagrant, virtualBox, etc) & hope everything starts working again magically :) will let you know if that fixes my issue or not, otherwise will keep bugging you :P Thank you for ur time and help!!

Comment: @Wal it is an environment variable