# Error during cloning project and can't unset credentials

Tags: git

I found the solution for problem when I tried cloning my project its shows wrong user/password, but upon trying to unset credentials using command:

```
git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

the error exist as:

```
Could not lock config file C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig:Permission denied
Could not lock config file C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig:Invalid argument
```

Comment: Something may have a lock on the `gitconfig` file.  Have you tried restarting the bash to see if that fixes it?

Comment: No, i ll restart as u said and see the outcome thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Similar [to this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778042/github-error-cloning-my-private-repository#comment56678163_33336623) ,try and restart "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" as administrator.

That should allow you to modify the system git config file.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is late, this may help someone.

In my case, admin privileges were NOT available, but luckily, restart of the IDE (intellIj) prompted for git password again.