# Git Clone not referencing config settings

Tags: git, ssl-certificate, config, fatal-error

I'm trying to clone a repository, but Git keeps giving me the same error:

```
fatal: unable to access '[PROJECT NAME*]': error setting certificate verify 
  locations:
     CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
     CApath: none
```

*Removed by me

There is no ssl folder in `/mingw64/libexec`.  I have changed the --system and --global settings for sslCAinfo and sslverify to refer to an ssl directory in mingw64 that does exist and to not verify ssl at all, but Git doesn't seem to be reading those settings.  I set them as follows:

`http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

`http.sslverify=false`

But even with those settings, Git gives the error citing `/libexec/ssl`.  I can't find anywhere else it could be reading that location from either.  I've reinstalled Git dozens of times over the past week trying to see if that would fix it, but nothing is helping.

Comment: *I have changed the --system and --global settings for sslCAinfo and sslverify to refer to an ssl directory in mingw64 that does exist* can you add the settings that you set for these (edit your question to include the relevant portion of `git config --list`).

Comment: Possible same issue as [Github error cloning my private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3778042/1072229)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github: error cloning my private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778042/github-error-cloning-my-private-repository)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Git's error is completely misleading!

- Setting `http.sslcainfo` to anything did not change the location git was claiming to look for the cert. Error was always a non-existent cert in `.../libexec/...`
- Setting `http.sslverify=false` had no effect
- Placing a cert file in the `.../libexec/...` location that git was looking for resulted in git crashing

My issue was that I had set `HTTPS_PROXY` env variable to a bad proxy url. This was causing an issue even though I had a `NO_PROXY` environment variable for the repo's url. Fixing (or removing) the `HTTPS_PROXY` url solved the issue.

Also, setting git's config for `http.https://some-url.com.proxy=` (i.e to nothing) resolved the problem as well irrespective of the `HTTPS_PROXY` setting.