# Real solution to clone Visual Studio 2019 to private Repository on github

Tags: visual-studio, github

I have searched through many answers on how to clone visual studio code to private repository on GitHub, however I keep on receiving the same error.

```
error setting certificate verify locations
ca path none
```

I have tried following solutions to create a certificate and to change network provider to secure channel, but I still receive the same error!

Anyone has a *clear* guide to clone my code to GitHub PRIVATE repository?

Answer (score 1):

[As seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3778244/6309), you should make sure your existing certificates included with Git For Windows are referenced in your global configuration:

```
git config --system http.sslcainfo /ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

That file is in the Git installation path, under:

- ./mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
- ./usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt

Then, relaunch Visual Studio, and check if the error message persists.

Comment: i cant fnd this file anywhere in the program folder. Where can i download it from?

Comment: @JaneCohen Actually, I have edited the answer with the right value. To be sure, I have added the path for that file.

Comment: thank you but i am still experiencing the same error. All i was meant to do was to copy the git config statement on git bash right?

Comment: @JaneCohen Yes. Does `ssh -Tv git@github.com` ends with your GitHub user account name displayed?

Comment: no i get an error ending with "The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.118.3)' can't be established.  RSA key fingerprint is..."

Comment: You should answer yes, and see if it goes further

Comment: thanks for your reply. After answering yes, i get the error "Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,140.82.118.4' (RSA) to the list of known hosts....
 git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)."

Comment: @JaneCohen Did you register your public key (id_rsa.pub content) to your GitHub account?

Comment: no. I am new to github. is this the issue? how do i register one?

Comment: @JaneCohen That would an issue indeed: follow https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account