# remote: Repository not found. on my own github

Tags: git, github

OS: Windows10
git version: 2.23.0.windows.1

few months ago I've forked a repository and everything worked perfectly. I've had to hard reset my windows, now whenever I try to clone forked repository using it `git clone 'https://github.com/user_name/repo_name.git'`.

it gives me 
`remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/user_name/repo_name.git/' not found`

running `git config --list` all of my credentials are correct. What might be the cause?

following @VonC 
**first**, I've tried `git clone https://github.com/user_name/repo`

which outputs
`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user_name/repo/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443`

**second**, I can access repo by inserting `https://github.com/user_name/repo` successfully.

**third**, running `git config --global http.sslBackend "openssl"` then trying to clone git still render same `repo not found`

**Fourth**, by running `git config -l` I get `http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

so now running `git config --system http.sslcainfo "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\curl-ca-bundle.crt"`, it should work but

it gives me `error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied`

Answer (score 1):

First, try git clone https://github.com/user_name/repo_name (no quotes, no final `.git/`)

Second, double-check the case (upercase, lowercase) of your URL, trying to go to git clone `https://github.com/user_name/repo_name` in a browser to see if it is visible/accessible.

Note that `git config` includes only user.name/user.email, which are not credentials (only settings used for authorship when creating new commits)
Credentials would matter only if your repository is private.

Regarding the OpenSSL error message, check if `git config --global http.sslBackend "openssl"` helps, following [`desktop/desktop` issue 3326](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3326#issuecomment-359277311).
Make sure your certificates (included with Git For Windows) are referenced as well (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3778244/6309)):

```
git config --system http.sslcainfo "C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

(adapt the path according to your own Git installation folder)

Comment: but why is this happening? I am copying url straight from github clone or download green button

Comment: @What OS are you on? What version of Git are you using? Is it a private repository?

Comment: @haneulkim Note: the Download green button should not give you a final '/' at the end of the URL.

Comment: yeah I might of had accidently added '/' at the end. I've forked private repo however when I can see my SSH for this repo in my settings

Comment: I don't even see curl-ca-bundle.crt on by \git\bin folder

Comment: Does `git config -l` includes `http.sslcainfo=/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`?

Comment: Yes, it was different path but running it with correct path still gives me same error