# Regarding Git fails

Tags: git, gitlab, fetch

I tried to fetch my colleague repository with the below comments

1. `git remote add jon-repo https://gitlab.XXXX/xx.git`
2. `git checkout jon-repo/20.5.1_CJ`

I am getting error of
error : pathspec 'jon-repo/20.5.1_C' did not match any files known to git

I can access his repo via GitLab portal and 20.5.1_CJ is one branch.

I usually fork and do, But here I was told no need to fork and just give the above comments

Comment: The title of this question should be something along the lines of "`git checkout` fails when I forget to run `git fetch` first", although that's almost its own answer. The question you *meant* to ask, I think, is "why is my `git fetch` failing" but that is a duplicate of existing questions.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to fetch from jon-repo.

Comment: git fetch jon-repo  -- > GIVE ME ERROR --fatal:unable to access 'httpsxxxx/xx.git/':error setting certificate verify location: CFfile"c:/userxxx/ca-bundle.crt   CApath:none

Comment: But that's not Git's fault and is a totally different question. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778042/github-error-cloning-my-private-repository. My answer is correct for the question you asked.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not saying git fault. I am here to fine solution to the problem. I checked with the person he said he already provide authorization. So here to check with the experts

Comment: Thanks it is authorization issue .